# Document object focus event not working properly in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to bind focus event to document which has few input fields.

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('focus', this.adjustFocus);
}
adjustFocus(e: SyntheticEvent) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

But adjustFocus method not been called when I change focus from one input to another. But method been called for events like click, scroll.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hirantha129/nbtqp7sx/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try adding a third argument to the eventListener as follows

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('focus', this.adjustFocus, true);
}
adjustFocus(e: SyntheticEvent) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: More read on this: https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link4